# this.props.navigation.goback() not working well when using DrawerNavigator

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-stack, react-navigation-drawer

This app first to go A's screen, then B, C and D. Then when being in D, I should press a Touchable Opacity to be redirected to C, but it goes to the A one.

```
--App.js-----------------------------------------

const AppDrawerNavigator = createDrawerNavigator({
   A: {screen: A},
   B: {screen: B},
   C: {screen: C},
   D: {screen: D},
   ...

const App = createAppContainer(AppDrawerNavigator);
export default App;

--D.js------------------------------------------

   <View>
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.props.navigation.goBack()}>
                    <Image source={require('../images/icons/goBackIcon.png')}/>
      </TouchableOpacity>
   </View>
```

Then when I try to use *this.props.navigation.goBack()* in screen D for example, it goes to A screen (the first one in the list). It was expected to go to C screen.

I searched solutions and I found out that combining StackNavigator with DrawerNavigator would be a great idea, but i don't know actually how to do it correctly.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something like this:

```
const AppDrawerNavigator = createDrawerNavigator({
   A: createStackNavigator({
      B: {screen: B},
      C: {screen: C},
      D: {screen: D},
   }),
...
```

goBack() method will work as you want inside the stack